# Simple function returning number that I didn't expect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, fibonacci

I have this simple function on the test on paper. My answer was `9` yet when I came home `console.log(fib(6))` game my the result of `8`. Why?

Also I asked my professor, he gave me this chart and still I didn`t understand it. Any help?

[image: fibonacci chart]

```js
function fib(num1) {
  if (num1 <= 2) {
    return num1 = 1;
  } else {
    return fib(num1 - 1) + fib(num1 - 2);
  }
}

console.log(fib(6));
```

Comment: You have your math wrong

Comment: I seriously do not know what more to say after that chart. Can you elaborate a bit on what about the chart you do not understand?

Comment: Shouldn’t this be moved to math overflow?

Comment: **Side Note:** `return num1 = 1;` can just be `return 1;`

Comment: You know that fib(6) is supposed to be 8 right ?

Comment: @Vivick you mean 8 :)

Comment: `(f(0) = 0 ∧ f(1) = 1) ⇒ (f(2) = 1)`, `(f(1) = 1 ∧ f(2) = 1) ⇒ (f(3) = 2)`, `(f(2) = 1 ∧ f(3) = 2) ⇒ (f(4) = 3)`, `(f(3) = 2 ∧ f(4) = 3) ⇒ (f(5) = 5)`, `(f(4) = 3 ∧ f(5) = 5) ⇒ (f(6) = 8)`,

Comment: @Vivick just made an nswer for it

Comment: @Vivick `fib(0) === 1`.

Comment: My bad, in UK sequences start from 1 so I improvised for 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [image: Chart]

**This chart demonstrates both what the code is doing as well as, fundamentally, what Fibonacci numbers are.**

Here's how that chart works:

1. The chart start at `fib(6)`.
2. Since `fib(x) = fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)`, then `fib(6) = fib(5) + fib(4)` as the chart shows through the arrows moving down.
3. You now have *two* values to include in your final answer `fib(5)` and `fib(4)`. The chart shows how to *repeat the above process for them* (split them into their smaller parts).
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until you get to `fib(2)` or `fib(1)`, which is *automatically equal to `1` by definition*.
5. At the end, sum all of the `1`s at the bottom of the chart (there are 8 of them).

**This follows along with your code:**

```js
function fib(num1) {
  // Start with a number (Step 1 on the chart).
  if (num1 <= 2) {
    // If it is <= 2, return 1 (Step 4 on the chart)
    return num1 = 1;
  } else {
    // Break it down into smaller parts (Step 2 on the chart) 
    // and recursively repeat the process for the new parts (Step 3 on the chart).
    return fib(num1 - 1) + fib(num1 - 2);
  }
}

console.log(fib(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

This program is famous [Fibonacci](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci) program. That is every number after the first two is the sum of the two preceding ones. Such as:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13.....
```

As you can see, the sixth number is 8.

Now we are talking how to solve this problem. First, you should know the recurrence relation is:

```
F(i) = F(i - 1) + F(i - 2)
```

And F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1.

So the code should be:

```
function fib(num1) {
    if (num1 <= 2) return 1;
    return fib(num1 - 1) + fib(num1 - 2);
}
```

And this is not the efficient way to solve this problem, because it have overlap sub problem. You can try memorization to solve it!